# In Qt how can I delay a member function's return until a signal is received?

Tags: c++, qt, loops, recursion

I want to use a recursive procedure to iterate through a large number of images in Qt: essentially the image is repeatedly quartered (up to a limit) and the user is asked whether the image passes or fails - ie if the image passes at large dimensions we call our function again with smaller dimensions (until we reach the limit), if it fails we return and so pass back up the hierarchy.

This approach seems to run into a roadblock with Qt's event-driven approach - I cannot see how I can pause the loop while waiting for the user input - ie there is nothing like a "wait_for_button_press" method.

I know that this sort of approach is regarded as an anti-pattern in event driven programming, but what is the alternative way that doesn't involve holding lots and lots of state on the heap (as opposed to getting it held for 'free' on the stack)?

Comment: I don't know how you applications works, but you might use a `QMutex` or `QWaitCondition` to just halt the thread until you click a button or whatever to unlock the mutex. YOu should use a background thread to perform your operation anyway, I'm guessing.

Comment: Why don't you use a modal dialog for the user input?

Comment: Had thought about that, but it's a lot of compute power just to do this

Comment: Well, you can call qApp->processEvents() in a loop from your recursive method until your slot is called; it's an ugly and error-prone approach (e.g what happens if the user decides to quit the application while all your data is on the stack?) but it might work for your use case.

Comment: Using a model dialog or an own `QEventLoop` seems to me the best solution. I do not understand why you think it needs a lot of computation power.

Comment: Try running a process that opens and closes lots of windows over X and you'll see!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, in the end I decided that the best route was to implement more message passing code - wait for the user input to dispatch a message. It was longer code than if I had used/had available the 'traditional' call back type paradigm, but it worked cleanly in the end.

Answer (score 1):

QEventLoop maybe could help you. I start a http connection aside a timer with a timeout, all inside a thread. Then a wait for one of those had finish and return.

```
void MyThread::run(){
  QNetworkAccessManager qnaManager;
  bool isPost = false;

  QUrl url(myUrl);
  QNetworkRequest req(url);
  QNetworkReply *reply;

  req.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,
            "application/json");
  req.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader, 
            QVariant(postData.size()).toString());

  reply = qnaManager.get(req);

  QEventLoop eventLoop;
  QTimer timer;
  timer.setSingleShot(true);
  const int timeout = 400;
  timer.start(timeout);

  connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));
  connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));
  eventLoop.exec();

  if (timer.isActive()){
    //everything is ok
  }else{ 
    //timer elapsed, no replay 
    return;
  }

}
```